# Can't reach any of my services with url . k8s / traefik 1.7

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I'm having trouble reaching my cluster with urls.

I am using ingress to do so. All my pods are running well, and I can see they can comunicate, but I can't access any of my services from browser. I broke it, it has been working for 1 year.

Here is my Traefik config

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-deployment
  labels:
    app: traefik
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      volumes:
        - name: traefik-certificate
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: traefik-certificate
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: traefik-config
      containers:
      - name: traefik
        image: "traefik:1.7"
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: traefik-env
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/etc/traefik/config"
            name: config
          - mountPath: "/etc/certificate"
            name: traefik-certificate    
        args:
        - --configfile=/etc/traefik/config/traefik.toml
        - --api
        - --kubernetes
        resources:
```

here is one of my service definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: metadata-api
  name: metadata-api
  namespace: metadata
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "18000"
    port: 18000
    targetPort: 18000
  selector:
    app: metadata-api
  type: NodePort
```

And here is one of my ingress definition

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: metadata-ingress
  namespace: metadata
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: "basic"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: "basic-auth"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: datahandler.company.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: metadata-api
          servicePort: 18000
```

I can see pod,deployment, and ingress working well. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that AWS ELB had changed. I had to manually change my Route53 alias to loadbalancer. Not quite related with Traefik, but maybe it helps someone in the path !